# OPENCV setting fps

Tags: c++, opencv, frame-rate

i am working on Hough circle and trying to solve the fps problem.

I wish to limit my fps such that i can test what is the fps that is best for my device.

```
    time_t start, end;
    int counter = 0;

    time(&start);   
    //Create a variable to store image
    Mat src;
    //Create video capture
    VideoCapture capture;
    //open video from either a file or webcam

    //capture.open("C:\\Users\\Student-ID\\Downloads\\SPACe Mission IIIA\\GOPR0503.mp4");
    capture.open(0);



    //set frame height
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 120);

    //Set the capture FPS
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,25);

    //store whatever is captured to src
    capture.read(src);

    //Debugging purpose
    cout << "Vidoe opened" << endl;

    if (!src.data) {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\topening image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Create window to display videos
    cv::namedWindow("image1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;

        time(&end);
        ++counter;
        cout << "fps is: " << counter / difftime(end, start) << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So i included this line in my code

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,1);
```

However, this code seems to be fake, and it is not taking effect no matter how i change the number. 
Is there some fundamental thing i got wrong here?

And the code here

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 120);
```

Sometimes also have no effect on the frame size, i would like to know why.

Thank you

Comment: I may be wrong but im not sure it works for all camera models.

Comment: Remove all the redundant detail to a minimum example, you might get more people interested in helping if you do that ... You may even figure out what the problem is in doing so.

Comment: doesnt work for all devices afaik. You could just measure time yourself and if more than the desired number of fps is generated: drop frames (just dont process them).

Comment: hi, thank you for your replies
so is there a fine line between what device works and what doesn't?

I tried laptop built-in webcam, fps does not work,frame size works
I tried video file (mp4), both do not work
external camera, both do not work